# python mocked function not called

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I'm testing python code (A django 3.0.5 project although I don't think it's relevant), but I can't get the functions of my mocked objects to be called. Here is my code:

```
**myproject.mypackage.myhelpers**


def get_dict():
    return dict()

**myproject.mypackage.mythings**

from .myhelpers import get_dict


def use_dict():
    the_dict = get_dict()
    pass
    return


**myproject.tests.test_mythings**

from ..mypackage import mythings
import unittest
import unittest.mock as mock


class MyThingsTests(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('myproject.mypackage.myhelpers')
    def test_using_dict(self, mock_myhelpers):
        test_dict = {
            "hi": "foo",
            "there": "bar",
            "sir": "foobar"
        }

        mock_myhelpers.get_dict.return_value = test_dict

        mythings.use_dict()

        mock_myhelpers.get_dict.assert_called_once()
```

However in the end the test fails with error:

`AssertionError: Expected 'get_dict' to have been called once. Called 0 times`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
@mock.patch('myproject.mypackage.mythings.get_dict')
def test_using_dict(self, mock_get_dict):
    test_dict = {
        "hi": "foo",
        "there": "bar",
        "sir": "foobar"
    }

    mock_get_dict.return_value = test_dict
```

The [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) section of the docs explains it a bit.

From how I understand it, `myproject.mypackage.mythings` will already have imported the "real" `get_dict` before you do the patch. So if you patch it like `@mock.patch('myproject.mypackage.myhelpers')`, only the `myhelpers` module will "know" that it is patched. The `mythings` module will still have the reference to the real `get_dict`.

I think an alternative to the way of patching I did above, is to change how you import `get_dict` instead. Instead of importing `get_dict` directly, just import `myhelpers` and use `get_dict` as `myhelpers.get_dict`. Then you should be able to keep your way of patching the same because `get_dict` will be looked up from the `myhelpers` which would have the patched method.

Comment: You're exactly right! Or, at least what you suggested made the test pass

Comment: This is the answer. I'd like to add that when thinking about patching, one must think about imports during execution time, rather than how they're written. 
When you're patching `method_a` to test `module_b` having in `module_b` an `import method_a from module_a`, the patch you want is `@patch('module_b.method_a')`.

Comment: @thlik, this was not clear to me from the documentation at all. I'd like to try and summarize it. Patching must use the path from **where it is used!** for that specific context. **Not** from where it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

- replace `myproject.mypackage.myhelpers` with `myproject.mypackage.mythings`

```py
# @mock.patch('myproject.mypackage.myhelpers')
@mock.patch('myproject.mypackage.mythings.get_dict')
def test_using_dict(self, mock_get_dict):
    test_dict = {
        "hi": "foo",
        "there": "bar",
        "sir": "foobar"
    }

    mock_get_dict.return_value = test_dict
```

### Solution 2

- replace `from .myhelpers import get_dict` with `import .myhelpers as helpers`

```py
**myproject.mypackage.mythings**

# from .myhelpers import get_dict
import .myhelpers as helpers

def use_dict():
    the_dict = helpers.get_dict()
    pass
    return
```

### Summary

- solution 1 is better since it won't bother you to update the `import` style in all your `.py` files